# How to Split a Dictionary Value into 2 Separate Key Values

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary where the values are:

```
disney_data = {
    'title': ['Gus (1976)',
    'Johnny Kapahala: Back on Board (2007)',
    'The Adventures of Huck Finn (1993)',
    'The Simpsons (1989)',
    'Atlantis: Milo’s Return (2003)']
}
```

I would like to split up the title from the year value and have a dictionary like:

```
new_disney_data = {
    'title' : ['Gus',
    'Johnny Kapahala: Back on Board',
    'The Adventures of Huck Finn',
    'The Simpsons',
    'Atlantis: Milo’s Return'],
    'year' : ['1976',
    '2007',
    '1993',
    '1989',
    '2003']
}
```

I tried using the following, but I know something is off - I'm still relatively fresh to python so any help would be greatly apprecated!

```
for value in disney_data.values():
    new_disney_data['title'].append(title[0,-7])
    new_disney_data['year'].append(title[-7,-1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two concepts you can use here:

- The first would be `.split()`. This usually works better than indexing in a string (in case someone placed a space after the brackets in the string, for example). [Read more](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).
- The second would be comprehension. [Read more](https://realpython.com/list-comprehension-python/).

Using these two, here is one possible solution.

```py
titles = [item.split('(')[0].strip() for item in disney_data['title']]

years = [item.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].strip() for item in disney_data['title']]

new_disney_data = {
    'title': titles,
    'year': years
}

print(new_disney_data)
```

**Edit:** I also used `.strip()`. This removes any trailing *whitespace* like spaces, tabs, or newlines from the ends of a string. [Read more](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: Could you also use the strip function to remove just specific characters or no?

I have another dictionary where the title and year are already separate, but the years still have parenthesis:
imdb_data = {
  'title': [
    'The Shawshank Redemption',
    'The Godfather',
    'The Dark Knight',
    'The Godfather: Part II']
  'year': [
    '(1994)',
    '(1972)',
    '(2008)',
    '(1974)']
}

Comment: Yes, you can. Refer to link in my answer (this is the documentation for `.strip()`).

Comment: @TimothyC., just a reminder: please accept the answer that worked the best for you (not necessarily mine). Doing so helps anyone who searches for the same question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You're not that far off. In your for-loop you iterate over values of the dict, but you want to iterate over the titles. Also the string slicing syntax is [id1:id2]. So this would probably do what you are looking for:

```
new_disney_data = {"title":[], "year":[]}

for value in disney_data["title"]:
    new_disney_data['title'].append(value[0:-7])
    new_disney_data['year'].append(value[-5:-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_disney_data = {
    'title': [i[:-6].rstrip() for i in disney_data['title']],
    'year': [i[-5:-1] for i in disney_data['title']]
}
```

Comment: @Timothy C. Happy I can help!

Answer (score 0):

this code can do it

```
import re
disney_data = {
    'title': ['Gus (1976)',
              'Johnny Kapahala: Back on Board (2007)',
              'The Adventures of Huck Finn (1993)',
              'The Simpsons (1989)',
              'Atlantis: Milo’s Return (2003)']
}
disney_data['year'] = []
for index,line in enumerate(disney_data.get('title')):
    match = re.search(r'\d{4}', line)
    if match is not None:
        disney_data['title'][index] = line.split('(')[0].strip()
        disney_data['year'].append(match.group())


print(disney_data)
```

it searches for every line in the title if there are 4 digits, if exists then add to year, and remove digits and parenthesis from the title.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
disney_data = {
    'title': ['Gus (1976)',
    'Johnny Kapahala: Back on Board (2007)',
    'The Adventures of Huck Finn (1993)',
    'The Simpsons (1989)',
    'Atlantis: Milo’s Return (2003)']    
}

new_disney_data = {'title': [], 'year': []}

#split title into two columns title and year in new dict
for title in disney_data['title']:
    new_disney_data['title'].append(title.split('(')[0]) #split title by '('
    new_disney_data['year'].append(title.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]) #split year by ')'

print(disney_data)
print(new_disney_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using split and replace.

```
def split(data):
    o = {'title' : [], 'year' : []}
    for (t, y) in [d.replace(')','').split(' (') for d in data['title']]:
        o['title'].append(t)
        o['year'].append(y) 
    return o
```

Using Regular Expession

```
import re

def regex(data):
    r = re.compile("(.*?) \((\d{4})\)")
    
    o = {'title' : [], 'year' : []}
    for (t, y) in [r.findall(d)[0] for d in data['title']]:
        o['title'].append(t)
        o['year'].append(y) 
    return o
```